# pip is not recognized what trying to install pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Whenever I try to install pyinstaller I am not able to and I get the error "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
could anyone help me as it also affects me when I try to install directories.

Comment: If you've downloaded pip, it needs to be in your path variable. You can also run the executable manually (by doing `C:\path\to\pip.exe install pyinstaller`). If you don't have pip at all, you can use `get-pip.py`: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use full syntax to command, typing:

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: it then says "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: How did you install python? You should have been prompted to add python to your PATH variable when you installed it

Comment: in this case, you must have to add the python path to your PATH environment variable. If you're using any version of Windows, the fastest way to do this, on cmd: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\python\path`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed pip, you can install it by using [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Download it as a .py file, and run it using `python get-pip.py`.

To add it to your path variable so that you can run it from anywhere (assuming Windows 10), go to System/Control Panel, then Advanced System Settings, then Environment Variables. Find the path variable, and add at the end C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe (replacing XX with the appropriate Python version, and making sure that there's a semicolon between the end of the last entry and the new one). Save your changes, and you should be able to use pip from any directory in the system.

Comment: I have now gotten to the point where it allows me to type pip and shows no errors but when I do "pip install pyinstaller" nothing happens.

Comment: Does pip give any output at all?

Comment: There is no output after typing typing it, I have set up my path and everything.